# Is it ok to execute a PlatformThread with a virtual-thread-per-task ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-21, virtual-threads

I understand that instead of pooling `VirtualThread`s, which does not really bring benefits, a `Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()` should be used in order to wrap all of our tasks with new virtual threads.

I was wondering though if it should be discouraged to execute a `PlatformThread` with such an executor, and if generally `Thread`s altogether should never be passed to an executor.

```
try (ExecutorService executor = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()) {
  Runnable platformThread = Thread.ofPlatform().unstarted(someTask);
  executor.execute(platformThread);
}
```

The platform thread created this way will be wrapped with a virtual thread because of the `ThreadFactory` of the executor. I am trying to understand if this could ever make sense, or if in general `Thread` objects should never be passed to `ExecutorService`s.

Comment: The code makes no sense, as the platform thread is never started. All you are doing is passing the runnable action `someTask` to virtual thread pool executor and allocating an unused platform thread. Calling `platformThread.run()` is same as calling `someTask.run()`, it does not start the platform thread.

Comment: The advice hasn't changed: Never use a `Thread` as a regular `Runnable`. If the `Thread` class was written today, I don't believe it would implement `Runnable` in the first place.

Comment: **You are not executing a platform thread.**  You are using a Thread to wrap a Runnable, but executor.execute will just treat it like any other Runnable and will never call its `start()` method.

Comment: As @Slaw said, threads shouldn’t be used a runnables and the fact that `Thread` implements `Runnable` is a huge design mistake. Even back in Java 1.0 times, it was totally wrong to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> wrap all of our tasks with new virtual threads.

No, not *all* tasks should be performed with virtual threads. Virtual threads are appropriate for tasks that:

- **Involve blocking**, such as file I/O, logging, network calls, interacting with a database, and so on. In contrast, if a task is CPU-bound, such as video-encoding, use a platform thread.
- **Use `synchronized` only briefly**, around small amounts of code that execute quckly. Long chores inside `synchronized` should either be refactored to use a `ReentrantLock` or else run in a platform thread. (This `synchronized` limitation may change in future versions of Java, beyond Java 21.)
- **Execute within the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)**. If your task involves calling native code such as [Java Native Interface (JNI)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), use platform threads.

> `Runnable platformThread = Thread.ofPlatform().unstarted(someTask);`

As others commented, your code does not actually run in a platform thread. Your use of `Thread` as a `Runnable` means the `run` method of your task will execute on a new virtual thread in the existing executor service. The `Thread#start` method of your object will never be called, and so no platform thread will execute as a result of this code.

You’ve fallen into the trap of using `Thread` as a `Runnable`. Having made the `Thread` class implement the `Runnable` interface is a flaw in the API, a regrettable design choice.

> in general Thread objects should never be passed to ExecutorServices

As stated above, effectively you passed a `Runnable` to your executor service, not a `Thread`. Your code never started your `Thread` object, never used any `Thread` feature.

> generally Threads altogether should never be passed to an executor

The entire purpose of the Executors framework is to relieve us Java programmers of the burden of managing threads. In modern Java **we rarely deal with `Thread`** directly.

Focus on defining your tasks as `Runnable`/`Callable` objects, and submitting them to an executor service. The only time we need to think about threads is in choosing what kind of executor service to establish: virtual versus platform threads, and if platform threads, how many.

Keep in mind that you can maintain more than one executor service at runtime:

- Keep one executor service backed by platform threads for your CPU-bound tasks like video-encoding.
- Keep another executor service backed by virtual threads for most other tasks.